# How to make cell format change depending on checkbox value in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Here is what I am trying to achieve in Excel. My objective is to have a list of taks on the left and a list of tests in all the others columns.
What I would like to achieve is that when I check a checkbox for a task (for example task "a", all other cells containing the letter "a" get colored in green), like shown below:

[image]

Similarly, when I click on task b, all cells containing "b" get colored in green.
Then, if all steps of a test are in green, the text turns green and increase the number of tests that can be tested, like shown below.

[image]

The thing that I have tried yet is to do some conditionnal formatting but I cant find a generic formula that says (if my cell has the value of a cell that is checked). Help would greatly be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

**Follow these steps**

Right Click on checkbox of each cell, Start from B3 Checkbox. Click on Format Control at the end of option window. In the Cell Link Type the Same Cell Name of Checkbox, e.g B3
(for Each checkbox, you have to put its Cell link manually)

Select Whole Column B and then select the font color White. So the text TRUE or FALSE of selected or unselected checkbox will not overviewed.

**Copy this formula in D2**

```
=IFERROR(IF(INDEX(B:B,MATCH(E2,A:A,0))=TRUE,E2,""),"")
```

**Drag it down**

Select Column E, Go to conditional Formatting > New Rule > Use a formula to determine which cells to format

**Use this formula in there**

```
=AND(D2=E2,E2<>"")
```

Then Select Column G and select its font color White

**in G2 Use this Formula**

```
=IF(F2="","",IF(COUNTIF($F$2:$F$20,F2)=COUNTIF($D$2:$D$20,F2),F2,""))
```

Select Column F, Go to conditional Formatting > New Rule > Use a formula to determine which cells to format

**Use this formula in there**

```
=AND(G2=F2,F2<>"")
```

Select Column A, Go to same conditional formatting as above and use

```
=B3=TRUE
```

You are done